# tableview refresh crush Thread1:signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My app is a IM application, when the application into the background and once again back to the foreground  will crush.
This is my part of the code。

```
-(void)uiAddChatroomMessages:(NSArray*)messages{
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int i = (short)self.messageArray.count ;
    for (RTIMMessage *msg in messages) {
        [self.messageArray addObject:msg];
    }
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    [self.chatMessageTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.chatMessageTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.chatMessageTableView endUpdates];
    [self.chatMessageTableView reloadData];
}
```

Run to this code "[self.chatMessageTableView endUpdates]",It crush and prompt "Thread1:signal SIGABRT".

> 2016-08-24 15:49:18.500 RTIM_iOS_Demo[1834:1326398] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3512.60.12/UITableView.m:1716
>   2016-08-24 15:49:18.590 RTIM_iOS_Demo[1834:1326398] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The
>   number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (62)
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before
>   the update (57), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
>   from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number
>   of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18238adb0 0x1819eff80 0x18238ac80 0x182d10154 0x1876e1808 0x100072ccc 0x1000728b0 0x100095244
>   0x10009468c 0x100077d20 0x100241a7c 0x100241a3c 0x1002474e4
>   0x182340d50 0x18233ebb8 0x182268c50 0x183b50088 0x187552088
>   0x1000a5340 0x181e068b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

Comment: **Never** call `reloadData` right after `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. The insert method rearranges the table view automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your method you added to `self.messageArray` some new objects but added just one row. Modify your code to.

```
-(void)uiAddChatroomMessages:(NSArray*)messages{
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSUInteger i = self.messageArray.count;
    for (RTIMMessage *msg in messages) {
        [self.messageArray addObject:msg];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        i ++;
    }

    [self.chatMessageTableView beginUpdates];
    [self.chatMessageTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.chatMessageTableView endUpdates];
    [self.chatMessageTableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the stack trace it seems like your index path is wrong. You are using array count as row index, try with (array count-1), hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting you the number returned by `numberOfRowsInSection` must match with the new expected value. You might be returning a constant or a number of elements of an array which hasn't changed.